# Why can't I connect to a specific website?

Tags: internet-connection

Could you help me figure out why I can't connect to a specific website ?

When I ping it, I get 100% lost.
When I try to connect via the browser, it says Error 500 : The request timed out

When I tried it in http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ , it says it's just me.

There is no host file exclusion on my laptop. My ISP is providing changing IP's so I don't think I was blocked ; I've reseted the router but no positive answer

I don't even think it's malware related : I've tried to ping from Windows and from a Kali VM.... same result i.ei no response
What can I do ?

Comment: If your IP is constantly changing, a previous user of your current IP may have been blocked by the site. Try accessing through a proxy.

Comment: It is extremely rare for a website administrator to go to the effort of blocking somebody by their ip address considering it is trivial for anyone to have their ISP give them a new ip address.  Something else is going on.  Have you tried to change your DNS servers to a third-party?

Comment: @AFH I just tried with OWASP Zap proxy.... Same results. I get connection timed out

Comment: @Ramhound   I'm using google's DNS `8.8.8.8` and DNS.WATCH `84.200.69.80`...

Comment: @Ramhound - It's not at all rare: it has happened to me automatically when traffic analysers have seen my use of a site as suspicious, even though I wasn't misusing the site. But the proxy failure does indicate that something else is going on, as you say, unless of course he is running ZAP himself.

Comment: @AFH  Hmm the website I'm trying to access is like udemy...It's an IT course website. So nothing suspicious about it. I tried going through ZAP (btw I just went through ZAP, I did not make any changes) but it still failed

Comment: Have you been running ZAP yourself? If so you need to try it with an external proxy.

Comment: Can you get to website on another device in that same lan?

Comment: @Dave Nope. Devices on the same LAN can't access the website

Comment: @AFH  I just tried a bunch of those proxies http://www.proxy4free.com/list/webproxy1.html   Same result

Comment: All rather puzzling. Have you tried another network (mobile data, workplace, friend's network), first with another computer, then with your computer on that network?

Comment: Use your phone on 3g. Does that work?

Comment: What is the link? The website?

Comment: When I visit, I see a blue screen with an "error" message from the web team, which is `The web app you have attempted to reach is not available in this Microsoft Azure App Service region. This could be due to one of several reasons: 1. The web app owner has registered a custom domain to point to the Microsoft Azure App Service, but has not yet configured Azure to recognize it. Click here to read more. 2. The web app owner has moved the web app to a different region, but the DNS cache is still directing to the old IP Address that was used in the previous region. Click here to read more.`

Comment: @Dave Okay. I suppose it is down for everybody. It's weird that http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ said "Down just for me"...Thanks for your help Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because another website suggests a website is up or down doesn't make it so!

I've tried it and I get an error page as well.

When things like this happen, before diving into the nitty gritty, it's often best to look at the bigger picture first.

1. Can you get to the site on another device
2. Can you get to the site from your phone on mobile (3G/4G)
3. Can you get to the site from another device in a different location (on a different LAN)

If any of those is yes, then it most likely suggests it's something local to you and needs additional work.

If you answer no to all of those, then the issue may be outside your control

Answer (score 0):

Could be a DNS problem.

Try to check if the exact IP address (not just the domain name) times out.

Or perhaps a node between you and the thing is down. In that case I'd try to see what `traceroute` (`tracert` on Windows) says.

Comment: tracert works up to `104.44.9.239` after that it's all `request timed out` I googled that IP ; it seems to be related to Microsoft. Since the website showed an Azure error to @Dave, I guess I can't do much about the issue. Thank you